# Select first TD in every row w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I assign a style to every first cell of every row in a table?

```
$("#myTable tr td:first").addClass("black");
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` pseudo class instead of `:first`.

```
$("#myTable tr td:first-child").addClass("black");
```

The `:first` pseudo class actually selects the first element that was returned in your list. For example, `$('div span:first')` would return **only** the very first span under the first div that happened to be returned.

The `:first-child` pseudo class selects the first element under a particular parent, but returns as many elements as there are first children. For example, `$('table tr td:first-child')` returns the first cell of every single row.

When you used `:first`, it was returning only the first cell of the first row that happened to be selected.

For more information, consult the jQuery documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 10):

you were pretty close, i think all you need is `:first-child` instead of `:first`, so something like this:

```
$("#myTable tr td:first-child").addClass("black");
```

Answer (score 7):

like this:

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').addClass("black");
});
```

Comment: This method is slightly less efficient because you are using a loop, a `find`, and creating a function, whereas by just using the `:first-child` pseudo class, you aren't adding much processing that wasn't already in use in his original code. It's still a nice alternative, though.

Comment: @Justin Satyr what do you think jQuery's using? A magic wand ?

Comment: No, I am aware that behind the scenes jQuery uses all of those things but (a) I would expect that use of a single selector is faster than use of a single selector AND a `find` statement, and (b) it is at least more efficient in terms of amount of code to use a single selector.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#myTable tr").find("td:first").addClass("black");
```

Comment: This is less efficient than using `:first-child` because it has the same result but engages in a loop. It's still a nice use of the `find` method though.

Comment: @Justin you're right, I didn't know of the first-child selector working like that.

Comment: First-child doesn't help when a TD is placed after a TH, and you're trying to find the TD. In that case jq won't return to you the TD, cause it's not the first-child of the row, and than :first is handy.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$("#myTable td:first-child").addClass("black");
```

Comment: Yeah. :o) Oopsie. I'll leave it like this in case someone wants a way to have first cell of any table black.