# jQuery: For each rows first cell

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add up the values of a column in a table using jQuery. To achieve this I am first trying to find the first cell of each row and then add them together and then place this value inside an input field.

What is the best of doing this?

So far I have:

```
// for each row
$('table tbody tr').each(function () {

        $firstCell = $(this).index(1).find('input').val();

});
```

So I need to add together the first cells for each row. so essentially each instance of the $firstCell variable that is created. e.g.

```
$('output').val(parseInt($firstCell.val()) + parseInt($firstCell.val()));
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155293/select-first-td-in-every-row-w-jquery

Answer (score 1):

**JS:**

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
   $firstCell = $('td:first-child', this).html();
});
```

Above code will use first td element in tr and will return html(), just to let you know td doesn't have value, its not input field nor select or textarea.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will do, code is untested

**EDIT**: based on your latest changes I added the counter

```
// array to hold all cell contents
var firstCellContents = [],
    cellCounter = 0;

// for each row
$('table tbody tr').each(function () {

    var $firstCell = $(this).children('td').first(),
        firstCellContent = $firstCell.text();

    firstCellContents.push(firstCellContent);
    cellCounter += parseInt(firstCellContent, 10); // don't forget the 10!

});

// add all fields to the inputfield:
$('#inputField').val(firstCellContents.join(','));

// or add the total to the inputfield:

$('#inputField').val(cellCounter);
```