# Showing Information on button click java web application

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, web-applications

My project is java dynamic web application. I have servlets & jsp pages in my projects. On one of jsp pages, I showed table as below:

```html
<table border="2" bordercolor="#81BEF7">
<tr bordercolor="#81BEF7">
 <td>Customer Name</td>
 <td>Address</td>
 <td>Contact Number</td>
</tr>
<tr bordercolor="#81BEF7">
 <td>AA</td>
 <td>AA Address</td>
 <td>1111</td>
  <td> 
  <form name="detail" action="./custInfo" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="btnCustomerInfo" value="Detail.." />
  </form>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr bordercolor="#81BEF7">
 <td>BB</td>
 <td>BB Address</td>
 <td>2222</td>
  <td> 
  <form name="detail" action="./custInfo" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="btnCustomerInfo" value="Detail.." />
  </form>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Once user clicks on button, I want to show customer detail information as below:

```html
<table><tr><td>First Address</td><td>AAA</td></tr>
<tr><td>Second Address</td><td>BBB</td></tr></table>
```

I don't want to go another page, I prefer showing with message box. Those customer detail information are in array. how can I achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: use jquery to get the values from your HTML

Comment: but I don't have any fancy css items. simple table on jsp page.

Comment: who needs these *fancy css items* - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155293/select-first-td-in-every-row-w-jquery

Comment: how do I get value from array which is inside servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in different ways

**Option 1** (Preferred in your scnerio): As your requirement doesn't need for any server data, You can simply use any client side script or javascript library to generate the output as a function of the input.

For instance, You can use JQuery as below :

HTML

```
<table border="2" bordercolor="#81BEF7">
<tr bordercolor="#81BEF7">
    <td>Customer Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Contact Number</td>
</tr>
<tr bordercolor="#81BEF7">
    <td class="custemorName1">AA</td>
    <td class="address1">AA Address</td>
    <td>1111</td>
    <td>    
        <form id = "target" name="detail" action="./custInfo" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="btnCustomerInfo" value="Detail.." />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr bordercolor="#81BEF7">
    <td class="custemorName2">BB</td>
    <td class="address2">BB Address</td>
    <td>2222</td>
    <td>    
        <form id = "target" name="detail" action="" method="post">
            <input type="button" name="btnCustomerInfo" value="Detail.." />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#target" ).click(function( event ) {
var address1 =$(".address1").text();
var address2 =$(".address2").text();
     $("#output").append(
        "<table><tr><td>First Address</td><td>"+address1+"</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>Second Address</td><td>"+address2+"</td></tr></table>" );

});
});
```

**Option 2** : If you really need to hit the servlet in your server, You can use either ajax call (with out reloading the page) or you can add the values into request object attributes while forwarding the request from your servlet into your jsp page.